# With reading hebrew in urllib2 python

Tags: python, encoding, urllib2

I read a webpage which contains hebrew characters, using:

```
response = ('').join(opener.open(url).readlines())
```

The result I get is mixed, some of the characters come back as unicode, which I can handle.

Some of the response seems garbled. In a format I cant recognize.
An example of the recieved text is:
    שלך

More precisely, it looks like this (only a snippet...):

```
<h3 class="_52r al aps">About ‎גדי‎</h3><div>&#x5e9;&#x5dc;&#x5da; ....</div>
```

The text between the divs seems scrambled. Can I convert it to unicode?

Comment: Do you mean you cannot handle &#x5e9;?

Comment: Why use `''.join()` when you can just to `.read()` instead?

Comment: i can handle handle &#x5e9; but that's not what im supposed to get and i can't understand how to turn it to unicode. It should have been 'שלך...'

Comment: and @MartijnPieters, this does not solve the problem

Comment: @Akkabar: I posted that as a comment, not an answer, *because* it doesn't address the problem itself. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at HTML entities; use the [`HTMLParser` library](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) to decode these:

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> print h.unescape('&#x5e9;&#x5dc;&#x5da;')
שלך
>>> h.unescape('&#x5e9;&#x5dc;&#x5da;')
u'\u05e9\u05dc\u05da'
```

To read a full `urllib2` response, just use `.read()`:

```
response = opener.open(url).read()
```